# iOS: How to add different colour map overlays on the same map?

Tags: ios, android-mapview, polygon

I have a map-based application that currently uses MKPolygon objects in an MKOverlayView to show various buildings - works nicely.

Now I'm looking to add different colours for different building types, so how could I differentiate between the polygons? Should I subclass MKPolygon and then add my own attribute in the custom class?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you to check out. [Hazard Maps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) is Apple sample code that uses different colours in an `MKOverlayView` to make a Heat Map. It uses squares only, but I sure you could modify it to use `MKPolygon`.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks but that seems to get its data from elsewhere. Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the MKPolygon class has a title property of NSString type. Setting this to whatever value allows you to then use various ifstatements  in order to apply different colours to the different polygons.